# Suitable file host for software toolchains and git repo setup

Tags: file-management, git, continuous-integration, docker

I am trying to dockerize the build environment at work (I have seen something similar at my previous employment). I was able to do this however I realised it would be easier if I stored some of the files (eg toolchain installer, etc) on a local file server so that whenever we are required to perform software builds, a Docker image would be used and builds would  be running in a container environment. And also, we would just be updating our Dockerfile regularly whenever any changes for the build environment are required. What can I set up to achieve something similar to this?

FYI our source code is also stored in Bitbucket (not the best solution but it had already been set up like this before I started), but I don't have much experience with other similar platforms, nor hosting my own Git server. I would be interested in hearing some ideas about this as well (something that is not too daunting especially when getting a couple of other engineers to adapt to a new tool).

Our code base is pretty small compared to where I previously worked, so they hosted their own git server. The main problem seems to be running into that "works on my machine" issue as there is no control on the build environment used by each engineer. I would like to introduce a Docker-based build environment to save time.